# Problem sending mail "Client host rejected: Sorry, no xDSL here"

Tags: .net, smtp

I'm trying to use SMTP on localhost to send emails thru a simple mailform in asp.net c#.
For some reason all emails end up on the badmail folder. The .BAD file says:

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822;xxxx@xxxx.com.br
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;554 5.7.1 <IP>: Client host rejected: Sorry, no xDSL here
```

Anybody got any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/100007/problem-sending-mail-client-host-rejected-sorry-no-xdsl-here

put it on serverfault.com